# __GETSR() function is not compiling in GHS compiler

Tags: c, microcontroller, automotive, greenhills, renesas-rx

Am working on Renesas RH850F1KM microcontroller.

Am doing coding for Safety Mechanism for Code Flash ECC module.
In our code we are using __GETSR() function to store the PSW address for future use.
But am facing the following error.

**function __GETSR declared implicitly**

More info:
Compiler we are using : Green Hills Compiler (C:\ghs\multi_716\multi.exe)

Comment: You need to include correct header file.

Comment: @Nabuchodonozor, Thanks for reply, is it standard header file ? If you know can you please specify. I added all which I know.

Comment: Check tx_port.h. It might also be a problem of your system configuration.

Comment: Found the specific header file( v800_ghs.h ), now it resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is lack of __GETSR() symbol defined.

As you have noticed, the correct definition is in v800_ghs.h header file, which has to be included.